# Zip Plugin For Cordova Application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, zip

I am developing an app which requires set of files to be compressed in a single zip file. I know this can be achieved using plugins , I can write for android but don't know how to do it in iOS. However i am looking for the available plugin. Please let me know if there is any. I have searched a lot but found only for unzipping , I need for zipping it.

Thanks In Advance, Please Do Needful.

Answer (score -1):

In case you're still looking for, I get the same situation and decide to create the plugin, for now just android but soon iOS too [repo link](https://github.com/jjdltc/jjdltc-cordova-plugin-zip)

Hope this help.